# How to create response in Jersey using JSON Streaming API

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have set of JAX-RS resources producing large JSON responses. In order to gain additional performance, I use "low-level based JSON support" which is described [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7823) in *9.1.1.3*. The problem here is that I don't want to use object-model-based JSON API. Instead I defined resource like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/stub")
public static MyBean doSomething{ return new MyBean(); }
```

Then, I created MessageBodyWriter for it, and faced a problem. I should create JsonGenerator in overrided writeTo method and write what I need:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(
    SendBulkSMSResponse sendBulkSMSResponse,
    Class<?> type,
    Type genericType,
    Annotation[] annotations,
    MediaType mediaType,
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
    OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = 
        JsonGeneratorFactorySingleton.getFactory().createGenerator(entityStream);
    // write some stuff
    // that's all

}
```

You, probably, noticed, that I haven't closed jsonGenerator. And I surely have reasons to not close it, because in that case it will close underlying entityStream that shouldn't be closed (check *8.2.1.2* section [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6723)).
Now we've come to the real problem: I could call `flush()` method myself and neglect check for completeness, but I couldn't put buffer back to buffer pool.
I use common JsonGeneratorFactory, so all generators share instance of BufferPool. And this ruins pool concept — none of created buffers would be reused.

Comment: Is there a question here? And why is this better than [`StreamingOutput`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html)?

Comment: @MattBall, yes, the question is in topic. I've come with probable solution, but it seems that I need to close JsonGenerator without closing underlying stream somehow. Haven't thought about StreamingOutput, but shouldn't I calculate content-length myself in this case?

Comment: If you're posting a question to which you already know the answer [please follow the appropriate format for doing so.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/133242)

Comment: @MattBall I haven't said, that I know the answer :( And you haven't said anything regarding size calculation in case of StreamingOutput.